# Yield a random permutation from a list of generators of known length

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, permutation

I have a sequence of generators which yield objects that require a reasonable amount of memory (they are ipaddress.IPv4Network instances and yielding from them yields a whole ipaddress.IPv4Address instance).

```
gens = [a, b, c, ...]
```

Each generator has a deterministic number of elements it will yield, e.g.:

```
gen_lens = [17000000, 1024, 8192, ...]
```

I would like to take batches of yielded values, of `n` length, in random order. Each item from any of the generators must only be selected once.

My current idea is to get the total number of possible elements that can be yielded (equal to the maximum array index - 1), then iterate through this list in random order using something like the Fisher-Yates-Knuth algorithm, yielding the item of the given random index:

```
random_indexes = random.shuffle(range(0, sum(gen_lens)))
for i in random_indexes:
    # some windowing logic here to check which generator we should get from and set index appropriately, x = generator index, y = i - sum(gen_lens[0:x])
    yield gens[x][y]
```

So the end result is, I have a new generator which will yield a random permutation of all elements from my input generators, without having to store *all* the results of what my sub-generators are yielding.

It still requires to build a list of indexes, which is quite expensive when you have millions of indexes. Is there a way around that? Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand your question but it feels like `itertool.chain` might be the way forward. You can join iterables together without the normal expense of joining large iterables. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain

Comment: @scotty3785 that I think helps simplify grabbing elements with a random index! But it doesn't address the random permutation part.

Comment: OP, It seems your proposal is not taking care of the condition: 'Each item from any of the generators must only be selected once.' in a batch. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Thanks @AajKaal - I believe it is, because I am using a discrete list of all the possible indexes, therefore no duplicate items from any of the generators should be selected. I should really note that these generators are actually subscriptible which is not at all typical of a Python generator...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I did in the end. I believe this solution is better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/65240594/1014237 because it avoids using `random.shuffle`, so it never stores too many elements (i.e. it only stores up to your `batch_length` number of random indexes, instead of up to `max(gen_lens)`. The work of generating random indexes only takes place when needed.

```
def get_random_element(data, data_length):
    pos = data_length
    while pos > 0:
        idx = random.randrange(start=0, stop=pos)
        pos -= 1
        if idx != pos:
            data[pos], data[idx] = data[idx], data[pos]
        yield data[pos]


def get_random_idx_generator(n):
    # Create a generator of random indexes, n long
    return get_random_element(list(range(n)), n)
```

I'm consuming from this generator with `itertools.islice` so that I only store as many random indexes as I need at the given moment. The function also uses the index and the lengths of the data lists to figure out which it needs to read from.

```
# Yield a batch_size long list of random IPs, using the random idx generator
def get_randomized_ips_batch(ipnetworks_list, ipnetworks_list_lens,
                             random_idx_generator, batch_size=1024,
                             as_int=False) -> Iterator[Union[ipaddress.IPv4Address, int]]:
    random_indexes_batch = list(itertools.islice(random_idx_generator, batch_size))
    # Figure out which ipnetwork_list our index is pointing to and yield it
    for idx in random_indexes_batch:
        cumulative_len = 0
        gen_idx = 0
        for ipnetwork_len in ipnetworks_list_lens:
            if idx - cumulative_len >= ipnetwork_len:
                cumulative_len += ipnetwork_len
                gen_idx += 1
                continue
            else:
                addr = ipnetworks_list[gen_idx][idx - cumulative_len - 1]
                yield int(addr) if as_int else addr
                break
```

Comment: What is "gen_idx" and what is "cumulative_len"? The names don't make sense at all.  Also, your ipnetworks_list is a two dimension array? What is in it?  It is not related to the "gens[]" or the  "gen_lens[]" in the origin question.  

So I can't understand your answer, and I can't ran it either. Is the "random_idx_generator" the same of "get_random_idx_generator()"? 

downvote.

Comment: `ipnetworks_list` and `ipnetworks_list_lens` are equivalent to `gens` and `gen_lens`. The `gen_idx` and `cumulative_len` variables hold the value that determines where in the list of generators to yield the element referenced by the current random index (`idx`).

Answer (score 1):

Propose: 2 dimensional indexes should be used. Since generating indexes for second dimension beforehand is expensive I am doing it for only one gen at a time

```
gens = [a, b, c, ...]
gen_lens = [17000000, 1024, 8192, ...]
shuffled_gens_indexes = list(range(len(gens)))
random.shuffle(shuffled_gens_indexes)
for gens_index in shuffled_gens_indexes:
    shuffled_gen_items_indexes = list(range(gen_lens[gens_index]))
    random.shuffle(shuffled_gen_items_indexes) 
    for gen_items_index in shuffled_gen_items_indexes:
        yield gens[gens_index][gen_items_index]
```

This is very straightforward and simply gives items from one specific
randomly-selected-generator at a time.

Comment: This is really nice - it would be even better if the randomisation was across all generators though, which I think can be achieved with the arithmetic I already proposed in the question (`i - sum(gen_lens[0:x]`) - but as you mention, it does mean we must have a list that is as long as the sum length of all generators.

Comment: On second thoughts, generating a shuffled list of indexes for each generator in this way would lead to you having to store and shuffle a list up to `max(gen_lens)` long, which as we see is quite huge.